# How to get all the procedure name and definition in a given schema in Redshift?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift

When using Redshift, I would like to get the names of all the procedure that were created in a schema, along with their definition.

I know you can use the SHOW PROCEDURE command  to get the definition but that requires to have the procedure name.

In SVV_TABLE there is only information regarding tables and view but not procedure.

So if anyone knows how to get that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift doesn't have a system view for that yet but you can use tbe PG_PROC table and join it with pg_namespace to filter on schema name.

```sql
    select proname, proargnames, prosrc
    from PG_PROC
    join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_proc.pronamespace
    where nspname = 'your_schema_name' and procsecdef = true;
```

The `procsecdef = true` is to get only stored procedure definition otherwise you also get python UDF.

Comment: I've been trying to get the definition of procedures from this view as well as combining it to pg_proc_info, but I can't seem to get the argtype for `OUT` parameters. I've looked everywhere and can't seem to get it, but I assume it has to be somewhere. Does anyone know where it is? I assume it has to be somewhere or otherwise `SHOW PROCEDURE` couldn't recreate it