# How to list all the stored procedure in AWS RedShift

Tags: amazon-web-services, plsql, amazon-redshift

I was checking this, but not find the proper one. So I prepared one and sharing that query here.

Comment: See also: [How to get all the procedure name and definition in a given schema in Redshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59197970/174777)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    n.nspname,
    b.usename,
    p.proname,
    p.prosrc
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON
    pronamespace = n.oid
join pg_user b on
    b.usesysid = p.proowner
where
    nspname not in ('information_schema',
    'pg_catalog')
```

Comment: There is a very small mistake, missed out the schema name for pg_user.
```
SELECT
    n.nspname,
    b.usename,
    p.proname,
    p.prosrc
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON
    pronamespace = n.oid
join pg_catalog.pg_user b on
    b.usesysid = p.proowner
where
    nspname not in ('information_schema',
    'pg_catalog')
```

Answer (score 2):

This was really helpful. There is a very small mistake, missed out the schema name for pg_user.

```
SELECT
    n.nspname,
    b.usename,
    p.proname,
    p.prosrc
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON
    pronamespace = n.oid
join pg_catalog.pg_user b on
    b.usesysid = p.proowner
where
    nspname not in ('information_schema',
    'pg_catalog')
```